# How to put an Images and set its size in JComboBox

Tags: java, image, swing, jcombobox

How will I put the image in descriptions method that I want to put for every string in jComboBox in upper left corner? For example I clicked the apple. Then the description will appear in the middle while the image will appear in upper left corner of the panel.

Here's the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener,     ItemListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JComboBox<String> mainComboBox;
private JComboBox<String> subComboBox;

private JLabel label;
private String[][] descriptions;

private Hashtable<Object, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<Object, Object>  ();

public ComboBoxTwo() {
String[] items = {"Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit"};
this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

this.setSize(400, 400);

mainComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(items);
mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
mainComboBox.setSize(100, 100);
mainComboBox.setLocation(0, 100);


subComboBox = new JComboBox<String>();  
subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
subComboBox.addItemListener(this);
subComboBox.setSize(100, 100);
subComboBox.setLocation(this.getSize().width - 120, 100);


String[] subItems1 = {"Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

String[] subItems2 = {"Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle"};
subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

String[] subItems3 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);


label = new JLabel();
label.setSize(300, 25);
label.setLocation(this.getSize().width /2 - label.getSize().width /2, 25);
label.setText("This is a label: currently nothing selected");
label.setVisible(true);


getContentPane().add(subComboBox);
getContentPane().add(mainComboBox);
getContentPane().add(label);

descriptions = new String[][]
{ 
    {"The red color", "The blue color", "A green color"}, 
    {"This shape is round", "Looks rectangular", "Has three sides"}, 
    {"Didn't fall far from the tree", "Seems quite orangy", "Look i've got a  banana in my trousers"} 
  };    
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String item = (String) mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
  Object o = subItems.get(item);
  if (o == null) {
    subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>());
  } else {
    subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>((String[]) o));
  }
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
 if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

 if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0 &&      subComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
    {
        label.setText("This is a label: currently nothing selected");
    }
    else if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() >= 0)
    {
        label.setText("The first combobox has been altered");
    }

    if (e.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
        if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            FirstDialog firstDialog = new FirstDialog(ComboBoxTwo.this,
                    mainComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Please wait,    Searching for ..... ");
        }
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == subComboBox)
    {
        label.setText(descriptions[mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() -1]     [((JComboBox<String>) e.getSource()).getSelectedIndex() -1]);
     }
   }
   }

 private class FirstDialog extends JDialog {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 FirstDialog(final Frame parent, String winTitle, String msgString) {
    super(parent, winTitle);
    setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(msgString);
    JButton bNext = new JButton("Stop Processes");
    add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bNext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    bNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new  ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    t.setRepeats(false);
    t.start();
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    setVisible(true);
  }
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame frame = new ComboBoxTwo();
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!!. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own, custom renderer.
Proper examples are in Oracle's Swing tutorials.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

See section "Providing custom rendered"

Comment: I need the images will show outside jComboBox. It must show with the description. For example when I click the apple. The Image of the apple will appear at the left side of the corner while the description will appear at center. I already saw that guide, but the image will appear inside jComboBox.

Comment: Read article I have provided to you. You will need to create data model, that will contain all the data that needs to be displayed, and use listener that will fire events when user pick something from combobox, so the gui could be updated.

Comment: `I already saw that guide, but the image will appear inside jComboBox.` - No. The first examples shows how to display the image on a separate JLabel.